# How do I get the video to not start autoplay, and only play when on screen?

Tags: video, html5-video

On this website https://happyprime01.businesscatalyst.com/video-test.html  the site scrolls horizontally and has sections that have a video playing, filling the background. There are 6 sections with their own video. I want each video to start playing **only** when the section it is in is on the screen. Currently they all start playing once the the page has loaded, so video beginnings are being missed.

I have tried the script below but haven't managed to get it working.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video muted autoplay class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="img/PowderPuff.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>



  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            $('video').each(function() {
                if ($(this).visible(true)) {
                    $(this)[0].play();
                } else {
                    $(this)[0].pause();
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try removing `autoplay` attribute?, this attribute start automatically the video.

Comment: Good point. I have tried it in some of my testing but it didn't work either, in fact it makes the video not play at all, as with the 3rd section on the link above (the blue ball shape against the blue background). The video should show the blue ball exploding.  Thanks for suggestion though!